# Django Blog Page not found (404) - No Post matches the given query

Tags: python, django, view

I'm coding a blog with Django,There was an error 404 when I click on address http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/7/28/prim-algorithm-path 
No Post matches the given query. Raised by: `blog.views.blog_detail`

views.py

```py
def blog_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
    print(year,month,day,post)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, publish__year=year, publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    return render(request,'post.html',locals())
```

blog/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import index,blog_detail
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>',blog_detail,name='post_detail'),

]
```

mysite/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/',include('blog.urls',namespace='blog')),
]
```

Comment: That means that there is no `Post` with as slug `prim-algorithm-path` publised on `2019-7-28`.

Comment: Is `Post.objects.filter(slug=post, publish__year=year, publish__month=month,publish__day=day).exists()` == `True`?

Comment: You can print `Post.objects.filter(slug=post, publish__year=year, publish__month=month,publish__day=day).exists()` in your view code.

Comment: it's false but Post.objects.filter(slug=post) = True

Comment: That means date of post is incorrect. Check `Post.objects.filter(slug=post) ` date.

Comment: In [11]: Post.objects.filter(slug=post)[0].publish
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 28, 10, 49, tzinfo=<UTC>) 
but the date is same

Comment: ```Post.objects.filter(publish__year=2019).exists()=True,
Post.objects.filter(publish__year=2019,publish__month=7).exists()=False```
i'm confused

Comment: Run `Post.objects.filter(publish__year=2019).values_list('publish__month')`. Is `7` in values list?

Comment: <QuerySet [(None,), (None,), (None,), (None,)]> but there r several articles in the db that i created today

Comment: Maybe in your create view, `publish__month` dose not save. You should save `publish__month` to your create view to retrieve by publish__month.

Comment: Sry bro  I just learned Django so I'm still a newbie  what's create view means? I set this up '''publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)'''

Comment: I thought you write a create form and create post with this form.

Comment: Please share your models.py code

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jjgqNtBDm4/

Comment: I'm learning through the Django By Example this book,why that happen,the code is the same

Comment: I run your code and, create post. and it is correct.
Find `USE_TZ ` in `settings.py` and change to `USE_TZ = False`. And after run your code.

Answer (score 0):

## Models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('blog:post_detail',
            args=[self.publish.year,
                self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.